# How to do simple arithmetic computations with variables to manipulate other input parameters in latex?

Tags: macros, color

I am trying to make a template for my CV. I need to make different color shades for headings, and subheadings many more. I figured out how to make variables in latex such as r,g,b shown in cod below but I can't make simple arithmetic operations performed on r,g,b values (last line in code).

```
%define variables
\newcommand{\r}{80}
\newcommand{\g}{117}
\newcommand{\b}{184}

%use variables
\definecolor{headings}{rgb}{r,g,b} % color for headings
% I want 10, 15 and 20 are being subtracted from r, g, b
\definecolor{subheadings}{rgb}{r-10, g-15, b-20} % color for subheadings
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see no real difference between the two tints, but here you go.

Note that the model to use is `RGB`, not `rgb` (the latter uses numbers between 0 and 1).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\hr}{80}
\newcommand{\hg}{117}
\newcommand{\hb}{184}

%use variables
% color for headings
\definecolor{headings}{RGB}{\hr,\hg,\hb}
% color for subheadings
% I want 10, 15 and 20 are being subtracted from r, g, b
\definecolor{subheadings}{RGB}{\the\numexpr\hr-10,\the\numexpr\hg-15,\the\numexpr\hb-20} 

\begin{document}

\textcolor{headings}{HEADINGS} 

\textcolor{subheadings}{SUBHEADINGS} 

\end{document}
```

[image]